# How can I query between two columns while still taking advantage of indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Imagine I have a table contains all the chapters of a book and the start/end page from each chapter.

```
chapter |   start_page     | end_page
--------------------------------------
   1    |        1         |    24
   2    |        25        |    67
   3    |        68        |    123
   4    |        124       |    244
   5    |        245       |    323
```

I'm attempting to find out what chapter a random page falls on, let's say page 215 for example.

My first idea was to use a query like this

```
SELECT `chapter`
FROM `book`
WHERE `start_page` <= 215
AND `end_page` >= 215
```

Unfortunately MySQL can not take advantage of indexes in the above query which is a large problem due to the large size of my table.

After doing some research I came up with this query which does take advantage of indexes.

```
SELECT `chapter`
FROM `book`
WHERE `start_page` <= 215
ORDER BY `start_page` DESC     
LIMIT 1
```

The issue now is I want the ability to query multiple random pages while still taking advantage of indexes. It doesn't seem likely that I can modify my last query since it's so heavily reliant on limiting results to one.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks to a comment from Ray Toal I have a query which gives me the results I need with amazing performance.

```
SELECT chapter 
FROM book 
WHERE (start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= 73) AND end_page >= 73) 
OR (start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= 92) AND end_page >= 92) 
OR (start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= 300) AND end_page >= 300)
```

Comment: Is the idea that you want, in one query, to submit a number of pages and get as a result, a table with page numbers paired with their chapter?

Comment: I only need a table of chapter numbers in the result. I do not require them to be paired with the page numbers.

Comment: So somehow you want to submit a set of page numbers like 73, 92, an 300 and want to get back 3 and 5, correct?

Comment: Correct, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Sorry this one has me stumped.  If there was just _one_ input page, you can use your second query, which is great, or `SELECT chapter FROM book WHERE start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= ?) AND end_page >= ?`.  Is there any way you can modify this query to take in multiple inputs?  I simply don't see a way to even phrase the multiple page numbers input at the moment.  Interesting question.

Comment: Ray, this query does exactly what I need - `SELECT chapter FROM book WHERE (start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= 73) AND end_page >= 73) OR (start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= 92) AND end_page >= 92) OR (start_page = (SELECT max(start_page) FROM book WHERE start_page <= 300) AND end_page >= 300)` It may not be the prettiest query but it does solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as this?

```
select max(chapter)
from book
where start_page <= 215;
```

If end pages follow previous start pages, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add two composite indices:

```
ALTER TABLE book
    ADD INDEX `page_range_from_start` (start_page, end_page)
    ADD INDEX `page_range_from_end` (end_page, start_page)
```

And proceed with your original query:

```
SELECT `chapter`
FROM `book`
WHERE
    `start_page` <= 215
    AND `end_page` >= 215
```

MySQL will choose the index leading with the column that will give it the fewest remaining rows to scan, and then it will have a second part of the index to reduce to the single desired row (without a scan).

Comment: I tried this with my first query originally. MySQL does not take very good advantage of those indexes and my queries average a couple of seconds each due to the size of my table.

Comment: In comparison - my second query averages .0005 seconds on the same table. The issue of course being the fact I can only query one page at a time.

Comment: Interesting. Does forcing an index have any impact?

Comment: Forcing indexes does not seem to have a noticeable impact.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically-valid equivalent of Bohemian's `INTERSECT` solution (requires a unique index of some kind and large join buffer):

```
SELECT
    chapter
FROM
    book AS book_l
    JOIN book AS book_r
    USING (id)
WHERE
     book_l.start_page <= 215
     AND book_r.end_page >= 215;
```

Or a temptable approach (requires a single index on each of start_page and end_page):

```
SELECT chapter FROM (
    SELECT * FROM book WHERE start_page <= 215
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM book WHERE end_page >= 215
) AS derived WHERE start_page <= 215 AND end_page >= 215
```

Comment: I tried both queries with the indexes. The first query seems to average around a second while the second one averages about 10 seconds.